# subdomain with different ip than host isn't working

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have a website `http://example.com` that needs a subdomain `http://shop.example.com`

In IIS I set up a new website for the shop website and set the hostname binding to `shop.example.com`

in DNS I tried both adding an A Record to the example.com zone file and that a record's host name is `shop` with a fully qualified domain name of `shop.example.com` and points to the new ip address.

That didn't work so I set up a new forward lookup zone file of `shop.example.com` with an a record with the host as `same as parent folder` and the FQDN as `shop.example.com` and it points to the new ip address.

Neither of these solutions work and I'm not sure which is the right one or what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is the new IP bound to the server and to IIS?

Comment: This could be a routing issue, a firewall issue, a NAT issue, etc. Why not use the same ip address for both names? You already have the host headers configured for this new site, so they'll take care of routing the incoming traffic to the correct website.

Comment: @Rex yes it is.

Comment: @joeqwerty I just tried that. I used IIS to make the ip address the same and in the domain host file added an a record to shop pointing to the same ip address as the host and it's still error not resolved.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the website bindings in IIS and the A records in your DNS zone?

Comment: @joeqwerty 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7wpnuru2loc88l/s1.PNG?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yzbga8zpo589gey/s2.PNG?dl=0

Comment: You're actually using two different ip addresses on the websites, which leads back to my first comment. What I meant was to bind both websites to the same ip address: 36.67.136.91. You've got the shop website bound to 38.67.136.91, which may not even be a valid ip address for you. My guess is that ip address isn't in the same subnet as your ISP allocated ip address range.

Comment: @joeqwerty that ip address is valid but I don't see what you mean  that I'm using two different ip addresses on the websites. I'm seeing both sites bound to the same IP address.

Comment: The shop site IIS bindings and DNS record show the ip address as 38.67.136.191. The DNS record for the www site shows the ip address as 36.67.136.191.

Comment: @prospector - if you are seeing both sites bound to the same IP, then you don't have the new IP bound to IIS properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open website with IP which is not working.

It will perhaps work in the following configuration:-

(1). If you have 2 networks with IP 36 and 38 and you hosted website on 38 series and trying to create an 'A' record on 36 series IP's DNS Server with successful "Zone Transfer".  This means, both DNS Servers should talk with each other.

(2) Or to fix this issue, go to existing configuration and change " Site Bindings" to 36.67.136.191 and point "A" record to this IP.